# Calculating user ages from array into foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to calculate a users Age based on the Dates of birth in the array, but am not getting any output with the foreach i need.

```
//User dates of birth
$userDob = array("1995-07-27", "1985-07-27", "1975-07-27", "1965-07-27", "1955-07-27"); 
//Create a DateTime object using the user's date of birth.
$dob = new DateTime($userDob);
//Compare the user's date of birth with today's date.
$now = new DateTime();
//Calculate the time difference between the two dates.
$difference = $now->diff($dob);
//Get the difference in years
$age = $difference->y;

//Display all ages
foreach($age as $ages)

    {
         echo $ages;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign `$userDob` to DateTime. You should use it in your loop.

```
//User dates of birth
$userDob = array("1995-07-27", "1985-07-27", "1975-07-27", "1965-07-27", "1955-07-27"); 

//Compare the user's date of birth with today's date.
$now = new DateTime();

//Display all ages
foreach($userDob as $date)
{
      //Create a DateTime object using the user's date of birth.
      $dob = new DateTime($date);

      //Calculate the time difference between the two dates.
      $difference = $now->diff($dob);

      //Get the difference in years
      echo $difference->y; //echo $age
}
```

***EDIT***

Its better return new array of ages than echo in that loop. And also I suggest use it as function with parameter for reusing multiple times.

```
function GetAges($user_ages)
{
    $ages = [];

    $now = new DateTime();

    foreach($user_ages as $date)
    {
          $dob = new DateTime($date);
          $difference = $now->diff($dob);
          $ages[] = $difference->y;
    }

    return $ages;
}
```

then later use

```
$user_ages = ["1995-07-27", "1985-07-27", "1975-07-27", "1965-07-27", "1955-07-27"];

foreach(GetAges($user_ages) as $age)
{
   echo $age . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted the answer, but have a question. This doesn't seem to work in another loop, but rather displays each age side by side. I have it inside another loop that displays a bunch of other information into spans also. Do I need to move this one inside that one?

Comment: Its what you want? Also better with parameter.

Comment: Sorry it is still doing the same thing. Here's my code if it helps. https://www.tehplayground.com/8MlAJcbK9w7OBATA

And here's a link to the page live im working on. You can see the age isn't breaking down. https://www.freerdarts.com/test.php

Comment: change PHP_EOL to  '<br>'. PHP_EOL is only plain print but you use html so put the tag.

Comment: I see, but it is displaying all the ages for each player, which I only need it to go in order of the array and display the corresponding one for each player

Comment: I've added 20 dates in the array to correspond to the 20 players

Comment: You need take my latest code with parameter function and remove array and loop from function body and return only one age. After that you will have function which accept one parametr as string date and return age. But its out of this question.